# A simple C program with unexpected output

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to solve leetcode 506. (Relative Ranks problem).
This is the c code not complete yet,and there's a puzzle that output is unexpected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,j,nums[]={5,4,3,2,1},tmp;
    char str[21];
    char **ret=(char **)malloc(sizeof(*ret)*5);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)     //bubble sort
    {
        for(j=5-1;j>i;j--)
        {
            if(nums[i]>nums[j])
            {
                tmp=nums[i];
                nums[i]=nums[j];
                nums[j]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(i<3)
        {
            if(i==0)
            *(ret+i)="Gold Medal";
            else if(i==1)
            *(ret+i)="Silver Medal";
            else
            *(ret+i)="Bronze Medal";
        }
        else
        {

            sprintf(str,"%d",nums[i]);      
            *(ret+i)=str;   
            //printf("%s ",*(ret+i));
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%s ",*(ret+i));

}
```

I think the output should be:

> Gold Medal
>   Silver Medal
>   Bronze Medal
>   4
>   5

but the actual output is:

> Gold Medal
>   Silver Medal
>   Bronze Medal
>   5
>   5

ans:

```
else
        {
            char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
            sprintf(str,"%d",nums[i]);      
            *(ret+i)=str;   
            //printf("%s ",*(ret+i));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `str` twice in your first loop. `ret[3]` and `ret[4]` both point to the same memory address. When you output your array, in your second loop, you will therefore get `5` twice, because its value is overwritten in the previous loop.

The statement `*(ret+i) = str;` does not copy the value of the variable `str`, but simply points `ret+1` to the address of `str`. The address of `str` does not change when using `sprintf` to assign values to its bytes.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I got it. Is there any alternative way to solve the problem?

Comment: Allocate a memory region to `sprintf` to, then point your array item to the new memory address.

Comment: I have tried to allocate **str to store data, but it Segmentation Fault. like this sprintf(str[i],"%d",nums[i]);      
            *(ret+i)=str[i];

Comment: No, use `malloc` inside the loop to allocate memory. Then `sprintf` to that memory. Have your array elment  point to the newly allocated memory address/area.

Comment: oh! I got ! thank you very much: )

Comment: @Howard and then of course do not forget to `free` your allocated memory, as soon as you do not need it anymore.

Comment: ok, I know thx :)